# How to perform an increment operation, like so, in list comprehension ?

Tags: python-3.x

```
a = [1,2,20,3,30,300]
b = []
count = 0
for i in range(1,4):
    b.append(sum(a[count:count+i]))
    count += i
print(b)
```

Generates output:

```
[1,22,333]
```

How can the operation : count += i, in the program above be performed inside a list comprehension which returns the same output list as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values of `count` are the [triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number). They can be computed directly from `i`:

```
a = [1, 2, 20, 3, 30, 300]
b = []
for i in range(3):  # 0-based instead of 1-based
    # calculate the triangular number
    count = i * (i + 1) // 2

    # add back the 1 for the now 0-based i
    b.append(sum(a[count:count + i + 1]))
print(b)
```

From there, we can do this all in a single (albeit a bit redundant) list comprehension:

```
b = [sum(a[i * (i + 1) // 2:i * (i + 1) // 2 + i + 1]) for i in range(3)]
```